# Does anyone knows, where Delphi 7 caches the DCU files?

Tags: delphi, caching, delphi-7, dcu

I have had an older version of Eldos SecureBlackBox installed. Now I deinstalled it and installed the latest version. Unfortunately Delphi caches the old DCU file, so I can not use the new property from the new dcu file.

Does anyone knows, where Delphi 7 caches the DCU files?
What I have to clear, that the new DCU file is loaded?

I have tried clean up with CCLeaner, but without success.
Thanks

Walter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delphi doesn't "cache DCU files" except in memory when it's compiling.

If you have new properties that you can't access in the new components, you haven't properly uninstalled the old ones, and the IDE is getting its information from the old designtime/runtime packages.

You need to properly remove the old packages and dcus before installing the new ones, and then properly install the new packages into the IDE. The DCUs by default are installed in the `SecureBlackBox\Sources` folder after installation (they're created there when the packages are compiled and installed).

You may also need to remove the compiled package files (.dpc) from your computer before installing the new ones. Search your computer for `*.dcp` files; you should find several of them related to SecureBlackBox in your `My Documents` folder. They should be removed before installing the new versions as well.

Comment: please see: https://eldos.com/forum/read.php?FID=7&TID=4240&MID=23832&sphrase_id=425838#message23832 the reason was that the UAC was not turned off and the dcu was in the VirtualStore

Comment: That's not Delphi caching the DCU file, however; that's Windows virtualizing a folder because of UAC. They're not the same thing. :-)

Comment: Thanks Ken, yes I just brushed up my UAC knowledge of WIN 7.